# React-Router - Error When Using <Switch> Outside an Array Map of Routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm using React router to dynamically generate Routes from an array. If none of the paths are matched, then I wish to show a 404 page.

The problem I'm having is that I'm seeing the error below in the console when wrapping the array map with `<Switch>`:

> Warning: React does not recognize the `computedMatch` prop on a DOM
>   element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom
>   attribute, spell it as lowercase `computedmatch` instead. If you
>   accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM
>   element.

Please see a sample of my code below:

```
const sections = [
    'section1',
    'section2',
    'section3'
];

<Switch>

    {/* If only /section/ is loaded in the browser, redirect to the first section */}
    <Route exact path="/section" render={() => (
        <Redirect to="/section1/home" />
    )}/>

    {/* Map through the sections array */}
    {this.state.sections.map((section, sectionIndex) => (
        <div key={sectionIndex}>
            <Route path={"/section/" + section + "/home"} render={() => (
                <Section
                    testProp={'test'}
                />
        )}/>
        </div>
    ))}

    {/* 404 Page */}
    <Route component={NoMatch} />

</Switch>
```

If I manually create these sections as individual `<Route>` components and then wrap a `<Switch>` around them, the error doesn't exist, so I assume it's something to do with the array map.

I cannot manually create all sections though as we could eventually have hundreds of sections that require a Route path. I also need to be able to send multiple props to the `<Section>` component, which is why I am using the `render()` prop within `<Route>`

I'm probably missing something simple here. Could anyobdy kindly advise? Thank you very much.

Comment: I would use `<Route exact path="/section/:section/home" component={SectionsContainer} />` rather than looping arround and generating the same object multiple times

Comment: Hi Mohamed. Can I pass props this way? I'm not sure what `:section` and `{SectionsContainer}` are relative to.

Comment: Yes, what type of props you need to pass ?

Comment: Functions, section information, etc. So maybe I pass these to `<SectionsContainer>` then through to `<Section>` ? I assume `<SectionsContainer>` will contain `<Sections>` ? But then how do I pass to `<SectionsContainer>` in this example?

Comment: I think you are using a loong highway to achieve your needs. the only thing you need is the saction, and the container will be responsible for loading it. I ll try to explain my idea in an answer with code snippets

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187591/discussion-between-matt-and-mohamed-el-ayadi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you need to use a `match` in your url since the sections are the same and the only difference is there names.

Consider using one single route with a `Container` to load your sections:

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/section/:section/home" component={SectionContainer} />
    <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
  </Switch>
```

In the `SectionContainer` you can access the `section` from the `url` as follows:

```
const { section } = this.props.match.params;
```

or `const activeSection = this.props.match.params.section;`

So you'll be able to fetch from your back-end this section's information.

Moreover, if you need to pass some new props to your container, you can do it like:

```
const SpecialSectionContainer= (props) => (
  <SectionContainer
    special="this section is special"
    {...props}
  />
);
```

and then `<Route exact path="/section/:section/special/home" component={SpecialSectionContainer} />`.

Once in your section Container, you can switch over your known sections to load the appropriate functions, and if using a state management API like redux, it's up to your reducer/saga to decide what exact function implementation to call depending on the loaded section.

Hope it will solve your problem.

Regards.

**EDIT**

for example, using [`redux`](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react), you can do the following:

```
componentWillMount = () => {
    this.props.loadSection(this.props.match.params.section);
  };
```

this will dispatch an action that will be intercepted by your side-effect middleware (basically thunk or saga), and will perform an API call to get your data and store it in the `store`. and your `SectionContainer` will finally easily load them and pass them to a functional component to `just display them`.

Comment: Thank you for this. How can I send `special` props function back to the parent component? (The component where `<Switch>` belongs. Like this? `const SpecialSectionContainer = (propsFunction) => (<SectionContainer special={propsFunction()} />);` - When <SectionContainer> is mounted, it will invoke `special()`, then this needs to be sent to parent container where `<Switch>` currently belongs. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Why do you need to go back to the parent container ? Simply, if there is somethinf related to some section, it's up to the section container to manage it (functions and validation and everything). Do you use redux ?

Comment: And also, if you can explain what this module of your app will do ? So we can first of all think about a design to achieve it.

Comment: Sorry for explaining this badly. When a section is mounted, I need to pass a function through to the main module at the top. This is a module within the main component which has the Routes. This function carries data about the section that is mounted, so that the main component knows how to handle it. I will take a look and see if I can work with it on SectionContainer. I do not use Redux. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: You are welcome. Of course it will work in the section container, or else, we should make it work. You are welcole, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

From the React Document

> The unknown-prop warning will fire if you attempt to render a DOM
>   element with a prop that is not recognized by React as a legal DOM
>   attribute/property. You should ensure that your DOM elements do not
>   have spurious props floating around.

In this case, the child is your , so nonstandard props computedMatch are being passed to native dom node , thus React gives you a healthy warning. So, using <> or  will discard the warning.